# Reading the coefficients with Maple

Tags: maple

If I have

$$
a+(b-c \cdot a) \cdot x = 5+7x
$$

then I know that

$$
a = 5
$$

and

$$
b-c \cdot a = b-5c = 7
$$

Can I get this result with Maple?

If I just write `solve(a+(b-c*a)*x = 5+7*x)` it will solve it instead of just 'reading' the coefficient.

Comment: To assign a value to a coefficient you have to write: assign(a,5)

Comment: But I've found $a=5$ by hand by 'reading' the coefficients. I want to find $a=5$ automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is

```
solve(identity(a+(b-c*a)*x = 5+7*x, x, [a,b]);
```

which immediately returns

```
[[a = 5, b = 5*c+7]]
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could do as follows

```
 lhs:=a+(b-c*a)*x
 rhs:=5+7x
 solve(coeff(lhs,x,0)=coeff(rhs,x,0),a)
```

This will output $a=5$. You are solving the equation that the coefficients of the 0 degree terms on each side are equal. To solve for $a$ and say $b$ simultaneously you could try

```
 solve({coeff(lhs,x,0)=coeff(rhs,x,0),coeff(lhs,x,1)=coeff(rhs,x,1)},{a,b})
```

I hope this helps!

---

**NOTE:** The command $\verb!coeff(expression,var,degree)!$ regards $\verb!expression!$ as a polynomial in $\verb!var!$ and returns the coefficient of the term of degree specified in $\verb!degree!$.

---

Of course, defining $\verb!lhs!$ and $\verb!rhs!$ separately can also be replaced by storing the equation as $\verb!eq1!$ and then applying the commands $\verb!lhs(eq1)!$ and $\verb!rhs(eq1)!$ instead.